# Create runtime constraints and validate a map of fields

Tags: java, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I have a map of input fields that I would like to validate using JSR-303 by creating dynamic constraints at runtime.

Let's say the structure of my map looks like:

```
name: Foo
description: Foo description
```

Now, if I have a set of rules stored in some sort of config that says:

```
name:
    required: true
    minLength: 3
    maxLength: 30

description:
    required: false
    maxLength: 200
```

I would like to validate my input map using constraints created at runtime from the configuration above. I know we can [create custom `ConstraintMapping`s using Hibernate Validator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-programmatic-api) as follows (example taken from Hibernate Validator docs):

```java
HibernateValidatorConfiguration configuration = Validation
    .byProvider(HibernateValidator.class)
    .configure();

ConstraintMapping constraintMapping = configuration.createConstraintMapping();

constraintMapping
    .type(Car.class)
        .property("manufacturer", FIELD)
            .constraint( new NotNullDef())
        .property("licensePlate", FIELD)
            .ignoreAnnotations(true)
            .constraint(new NotNullDef())
            .constraint(new SizeDef().min(2).max(14))

Validator validator = configuration.addMapping(constraintMapping)
        .buildValidatorFactory()
```

But clearly this won't work for `java.util.Map`s as maps are not JavaBeans. So how do I go about something like this? A few things I've considered (cons with each approach):

1. To create classes at runtime using ByteBuddy or something similar and use that to validate using Hibernate Validator (sounds like an overkill)
2. To manually validate using a series of `if` conditions and throw a `ConstraintViolationException` (I'll be reinventing a lot of the wheel here)

I would like to understand what you would do in a situation like this.

Answer (score 2):

There are too many questions to answer but I'll try.

## Dynamically created constraint mappings

As the example describes it's available. There are two ways to create custom mapping.

### Create custom constraint mapping programmatically

Let's assume there is a POJO

```java
import java.util.Map;

public class Foo {
    private Map<String, String> rules;

    public Map<String, String> getRules() {
        return rules;
    }

    public void setRules(Map<String, String> rules) {
        this.rules = rules;
    }
}
```

The described constraints are:

- The map mustn't be null
- Max. size of the map is 2
- Key of the map should be 3 characters at least
- Value mustn't be blank and
- Value must be max. 5 chars

Like this:

```java
@NotNull
@Size(max=3)
private Map<@Size(min=3)String, @NotBlank @Size(max=5)String> rules;
```

Constraint mapping for that is:

```java
var configuration = Validation
        .byProvider(HibernateValidator.class)
        .configure();

ConstraintMapping constraintMapping = configuration.createConstraintMapping();

constraintMapping
        .type(Foo.class)
        .field("rules")
        .constraint(new NotNullDef())
        .constraint(new SizeDef().max(2))
        .containerElementType(0)
            .constraint(new SizeDef().min(3))
        .containerElementType(1)
            .constraint(new NotBlankDef())
            .constraint(new SizeDef().max(5))
        ;

var validator = configuration.addMapping(constraintMapping)
        .buildValidatorFactory()
        .getValidator();
```

Working example is:

```java
public class FooValidatorTest {
    @Test
    void name() {
        var configuration = Validation
                .byProvider(HibernateValidator.class)
                .configure();

        ConstraintMapping constraintMapping = configuration.createConstraintMapping();

        constraintMapping
                .type(Foo.class)
                .field("rules")
                .constraint(new NotNullDef())
                .constraint(new SizeDef().max(2))
                .containerElementType(0)
                    .constraint(new SizeDef().min(3))
                .containerElementType(1)
                    .constraint(new NotBlankDef())
                    .constraint(new SizeDef().max(5))
        ;
        var validator = configuration.addMapping(constraintMapping)
                .buildValidatorFactory()
                .getValidator();
        assertAll(
                () -> {
                    var obj = new Foo();
                    /*
                    expected violation(s)
                        map is null
                     */

                    var result = validator.validate(obj).stream().toList();
                    assertAll("Only @NotNull should violated",
                            () -> assertEquals(1, result.size()),
                            () -> assertEquals("{jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}",
                                    result.get(0).getMessageTemplate()
                            )
                    );
                },
                () -> {
                    var obj = new Foo();
                    /*
                    expected violation(s)
                        map contains too much elements (max: 2)
                    note: keys and values are not validated
                     */
                    obj.setRules(Map.of("name1", "desc1", "name2", "desc2", "name3", "desc3"));
                    var result = validator.validate(obj).stream().toList();
                    assertAll("Only @Size should violated",
                            () -> assertEquals(1, result.size()),
                            () -> assertEquals("{jakarta.validation.constraints.Size.message}",
                                    result.get(0).getMessageTemplate()
                            )
                    );
                },
                () -> {
                    var obj = new Foo();
                    /*
                    expected violation(s)
                        first key is too short (min: 3)
                        first value is blank
                        second value is too long (max:5)
                     */
                    obj.setRules(Map.of("aa", "", "bbb", "longValue"));
                    var result = validator.validate(obj).stream().toList();
                    var templates = result.stream().map(ConstraintViolation::getMessageTemplate).toList();
                    var expectedTemplates = new String[]{
                            "{jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank.message}",
                            "{jakarta.validation.constraints.Size.message}",
                            "{jakarta.validation.constraints.Size.message}"
                    };
                    assertAll(
                            () -> assertEquals(3, result.size()),
                            () -> assertThat(templates, containsInAnyOrder(expectedTemplates))
                    );
                }
        );
    }
}
```

### Create custom constraint mapping using xml

The `.addMapping` method have another signature which accepts an inputstream.

The xml definition is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<constraint-mappings
        xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/validation/mapping"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation=
                "https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/validation/mapping https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/validation/validation-mapping-3.0.xsd"
        version="3.0">
    <bean class="Foo">
        <field name="rules">
            <container-element-type type-argument-index="0">
                <container-element-type>
                    <constraint annotation="jakarta.validation.constraints.Size">
                        <element name="min">3</element>
                    </constraint>
                </container-element-type>
            </container-element-type>
            <container-element-type type-argument-index="1">
                <container-element-type>
                    <constraint annotation="jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank"/>
                    <constraint annotation="jakarta.validation.constraints.Size">
                        <element name="max">5</element>
                    </constraint>
                </container-element-type>
            </container-element-type>
            <constraint annotation="jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull"/>
            <constraint annotation="jakarta.validation.constraints.Size">
                <element name="max">2</element>
            </constraint>
        </field>
    </bean>
</constraint-mappings>
```

And this modification is necessary:

```java
var validator = configuration
        .addMapping(
            getClass().getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("foo_mapping.xml")
        )
        .buildValidatorFactory()
        .getValidator();
```

## Loading external classes

After when runtime bytecode generation finished those classes should load and loaded classes should pass to the `validator`.
So at first thing to do to create a classloader (`ucl`). After that it can be passed to `HibernateValidatorConfiguration`

```java
var configuration = Validation
        .byProvider(HibernateValidator.class)
        .configure()
        .externalClassLoader(ucl);
```

Technically it is available to create and load POJOs dynamically and run custom validation mappings but I don't think it is a good way.
Every time when you create a class or create a custom mapping a new `Validator` instance should be created. Although instantiating a new Validator is cheap but it needs a new `ValidatorFactory` which is very expensive (~400ms).